# Reducing number of dependencies in coordination classes

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

In a class that does mostly coordination work of its dependent services, is there a strategy to reduce the number of dependencies?

For example, consider taking a donation. My coordinating class might look like:

```
public class DonationService
{
    public DonationService(
            IDonationValidator validator,
            ICreditCardGateway creditCardGateway,
            IServiceBus serviceBus,
            IDatabaseSession dbSession,
            ILogger logger
            )
            { … }

    public DonationResult HandleDonation(DonationRequest request)
    {
        // 1. Validate
        // 2. Charge Credit Card
        // 3. Record in database
        // 4. Publish message to service bus
    }
}
```

If there were one more step in the process, I could easily see a sixth dependency arise. Perhaps logging could be a cross-cutting concern, but that's debatable.

There are simply a good number of steps that need to be taken within the single responsibility of taking a donation. I'm not including steps like "send an email" because I'm relying on a separate process to do that when receiving the donation message via the service bus.

I'm not sure if I could create a facade service over any subset of the dependencies in this group and am not sure what else I should do. Any suggestions on removing this code smell would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into scenarios very similar to this one and it turns out (always) to be due to poor design...actually, a couple senior architects pointed that out to me in the past. Usually, because of giving too much responsibility to a single object. Now, as we all know sometimes a full-leg re-design is not the smartest or affordable way to address the issue, but you should always consider it in first place when you have a design issue. What can you do to avoid a bloated constructor? Here are some options:

1- Provide a default implementation, add a default constructor that initializes a default implementation of these dependencies...perhaps using a factory object so you don't end up initializing concrete object implementations. Overload the constructor by having these overloads call the default constructor

2- Delegate some responsibility to some kind of "intermediary" object, for example you might want to move the servicebus and database responsibility to a a separate object and then move the logging to these dependencies

Comment: A default implementation really just hides the issue. You still have a SRP problem. The issue I'm trying to resolve is the inherent number of dependencies in a class whose job is to coordinate other services. Perhaps this is really a case where more infrastructure, such as a workflow engine would be ideal.

Comment: looks like it's exactly what I suggested in option two...removing responsibilities from `DonationService`....but again sometimes a re-design is costly which is when you might need to resort to option 1...this is a decision that only you can make...at the end of the day only you can properly assess your situation and resources at ur disposal

Comment: Thankfully this isn't a redesign, but an initial build. One thing I did was take the suggestion of Lilshieste and created a Validating service that wraps the inner service. These are actually message handlers in my real implementation, and that worked well. One dependency down.

Comment: Voted up for the first line and option 2, but I agree with Brian that option 1 is not helpful.

Comment: Well, it's exactly what I've repeated over and over, we can't take things out of context and sometimes re-designing part of a system's architecture has massive implications...whether cost, time or both...at the time of answering I did not know he was in the initial phases of the development. But I've decided to leave it there because it still an option for those who can't afford a re-write

Answer (score 0):

Despite its name, a code smell isn't necessarily a bad thing that needs to be removed - it just signals a need for deeper evaluation.

It's perfectly legitimate for a code smell investigation to result in no action being taken, **as long as the design can be justified**. Of course, more often than not, code smells *usually* indicate a problem (hence their infamy).

For the scenario you provided, we could surely group some of the dependencies together; but can we do so in a way that helps readability/maintainability?

For example: it's possible that the "Validate" and "Charge credit card" steps could be merged, resulting in a "Process credit card donation" step. But it's also possible that the "Validate" step apples to the donation process as a whole (as the name of the collaborator implies), and not just the credit card portion. In that case, combining the collaborators would only lead to confusion.

One option you could consider is pulling an individual collaborator out of the class, and using it to create a [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) class. For example, removing `IDonationValidator` from `DonationService`, and using it to create a class like `DonationServiceThatValidatesBeforeProcessing` (with a more succinct name, as preferred).

Any approach you take should be evaluated with the mindset of making the codebase more readable. If having a lot of constructor parameters hurts readability, *but the alternatives hurt readability even more*, then stick with the status quo.

Comment: Both answers were good. I ended up using a decorator pattern to do some of my code consolidation.